# how to count the number of items in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

i have such tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_name VARCHAR(100) );
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id INT,
    amount DOUBLE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
);
```

I need to select number of orders for every customer

i have tried:

```
SELECT orders, COUNT(*)
FROM orders
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

but it dosnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
select
c.customer_id,
count(o.customer_id) as total
from customers c
join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
order by total desc
```

Above query will return count only for the customers which has data in the `orders` table and if you need to count for all the customer irrespective of there is data in the `orders` table or not you need `left join`

```
select
c.customer_id,
coalesce(count(o.customer_id),0) as total
from customers c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
order by total desc
```

Comment: If you don't need customers with no orders, and don't select the customer names, you can skip the left join and use orders table alone.

Comment: @jarlh yes that correct but I am sure customer name would be needed at some point of time from the first table and its better to use the join instead of getting it from the 2nd table. More over what if there are some other columns added in the customer table like `active` `yes/no` and I want to see only active customers data. So for long run its wise to make your query adaptable right from the very beginning.

Comment: Absolutely, very educational.

Answer (score 0):

You can write following query also

```
`SELECT 
    c.customer_id, COUNT(o.order_id)
FROM
    customers c,
    orders o
WHERE
    c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id;`
```